# Boo ASP.NET MVC template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, templates, boo

I've been searching around for a way to use Boo in ASP.NET MVC project. What I would like is a way to easily create an MVC project with Boo, like the included templates that the MVC project has for C# and VB. Does anyone know of a way to get Boo working with MVC?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own templates, but it seems like a lot of work for your own benefit.  I don't know of anyone that has done this already.